# AWS cloudfront with SSL issue in Lightsail - redirecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a AWS Lightsail instance with Wordpress. I needed to install SSL for this website. So i obtained a SSL certificate from AWS and installed it through Cloudfront. Once it deployed on Cloudfront i could able to access the website through Cloudfront given url such as,

```
http://url.cloudfront.net
```

And could able to access https website as well using,

```
https://url.cloudfront.net
```

There was a mixed content issue on website and i installed "SSL Insecure Content Fixer". But issue didn't fix. Anyhow after that when i'm trying to access the Cloudfront url, it's redirecting to origin url instead of serving the pages through Cloudfront url. I'm confusing at this point and hope someone help me.